# Fluid simulation - why gradient of pressure is the term $\delta q$ in the projection step?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, flow, navier-stokes

I'm learning stable fluids by reading Stam's paper.

In the paper, it says, according to *Helmholtz-Hodge Decomposition*, I vector field $w$ could be decomposed to a **divergence-free** field and a **curl-free** field. Thus:

$$ w = u +\nabla q \\
u = Pw = w-\nabla q$$

where $P$ is our projection P.

Given the Navier-Stokes equation:
$$ \nabla \cdot u = 0\\
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} = -(u\cdot \nabla)u - \frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p + v\nabla^2 u + f $$

Do projection $P$ to both sides of the above equation, we obtain

$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} = P(-(u\cdot\nabla )u + v\nabla^2u +f)$$

I think the projection is, essentially, used to **extract the divergence-free** component of a vector field. So, we want to extract the divergence-free part of $-(u\cdot\nabla )u + v\nabla^2u +f$.

Later in the paper, we have
$$ w_4 = w_3 - \nabla q$$
where $w_4$ is the divergence-free velocity field we want.

However, someone told me the $\nabla q$ term in this case is actually the **gradient of pressure**. I wonder is that correct? If it is, why?

Comment: Can you provide a link or a better citation to  "Stam's paper"?

Comment: I think the question is on-topic here on [computergraphics.se], but I don't think it quite fits our audience, and it would get better answers on [physics.se], so I'm sending it their way.